# How to create equation from the imported xy co-ordinates using python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, coordinates, equation

I have an excel file with the xy coordinates and I want to import them and create an equation using python. I know how to import coordinates and turn them into graph but how do I create an equation out of it. picture below show the coordinates. capacity is x and power is y. let me know if I should provide more detail.

[coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZtEh.png)

Comment: `how do I create an equation out of it` what it means?

Comment: like how do I create a code that outputs the equation when the coordinates are inputted/imported from excel!!

Comment: What do you mean by "the equation"?

Comment: like y=mx+b type equation

Answer (score 0):

You should split your question into separate pieces:

1. To read a piece of the excel file, you will do well with the `pandas` Python package, specially with the [`read_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) function.
2. To **plot** the data (turn what you call "equation", which is just a list of pairs of values, into a graph) you can resort to `pandas`'s [`plot.line`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.line.html).

In general, try to decompose your question into smaller ones, which have probably been answered before!

Comment: Let me rephrase it. I want to uses the xy cordinate to come up with a y=mx+b type equation. I know the basic python of how to import excel file and and how to plot those coordinate.